# Multiple CSS 3 background images - Add opacity to the top image

Tags: css, background

Is this even possible?
I have a box and want to add one background image over the other. But i want to add an opacity 0.5 just 
for the top image.

Comment: everything is possible if you share codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with pseudo element:

```
#example1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url(http://goldenageofgaia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Field-flowers-image7.jpg) 60% 60% no-repeat;
}

#example1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  opacity: .7;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("http://www.butterflyskye.com.au/Monarch%20Butterfly%202.jpg");
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Let8U/

Answer (score 1):

Check out: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ It would help somewhat.

```
#example1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url(sheep.png), url(betweengrassandsky.png);
  background-position: center bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

As you can see in the example given, there are two images - one center bottom and the other top left. For Opacity, I would do that in the image editor if I wanted to layer backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change a `background-image`'s `opacity`.

What you can do is add an extra element with the desired opacity and background on top of your box.

This snippet on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) shows an elegant way of doing this with pseudo-elements, so you don't need to clutter your markup to achieve the effect: [Transparent Background Images](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/)

Hope it helps.